# Questionable need for mutex with shared resources

Tags: c#

I currently have a mechanism where the 2 threads read/write the same data; though not at the same time; and do not use any synchronisation mechanisms.

Perhaps the simplest example would be (pseudocode)

```
x = 5;
startThread(changeX).join()
assert(x != 5)
```

thus we can be sure that the thread in question has processed `x` before it's read by the starting thread.

Is this undefined behavior (as the x might be optimised) - or is it safe?

My experience of c++ and my research so far would say not safe - but I couldn't see anything definitive.

Comment: The real question is, are there any chances of the 2 threads colliding? if the chance exists I would say you need to sync

Comment: @Prix let's go with there isn't.... is it still safe (for example could the compiler optimise something for me)?

Comment: There is also the possibility you read it before you write to it, is that behavior undesired? if so I would say sync, if there isn't then I don't see anything that would hold you back. The compiler will not create locks for you. if the compiler sees the code as useless it may optimize it yes. For example if you write `var test = true;` and compile it on release.

Comment: Your use of the word "seemingly" would cast some doubt on them never colliding.

Comment: @UKMonkey The way this code is written the parent thread *blocks* while waiting for the child thread to finish. The *sub*optimal part is that a new thread is created instead of picking an idle thread from the thread pool. You can use eg `Task.Run(()=>changeX(...)).Wait();` to use a thread from the pool or `await Task.Run....` to asynchronously await

Comment: To me the operative word is "seemingly." We can test multithreaded code forever without seeing problems, and then they occur as soon as our application is in some other environment. Chances are we just won't know when it happens, which allows it to cause problems longer. Then someone reports something but we can't repeat it. Then we repeat it but no one can figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos right - but that doesn't say if it's safe or not.

Comment: Too true - my doubt of the code I'm looking at shouldn't impact the fundamentals of the question.... let me adjust.

Comment: @UKMonkey it does - the other thread is *not* running when you call `assert(x != 5)`. The code has a different problem - what does `changeX` do? Ints are value types so `changeX` can't modify X unless it's passed by ref.

Comment: @UKMonkey what is `x` anyway? Variable? Field? Property? Why use a thread like that instead of eg `x = await Task.Run(()=>someHeavyWork()` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos member variable (class) - in c++ the compiler could reasonably look at this; and fail the assertion because x couldn't have been changed by the given thread, and there's no syncronisation around x to tell the compiler that it could change.  I just don't know the c# spec well enough to see if the same optimisations can be applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the pseudocode you are writting I can tell you this:

1 - Rule of thumb, whenever 2 threads are doing writting/reading on the same variable you need to take into account to use thread safe structures and you should always use some kind of synchronization between threads.

2 - While in your case you are working with atomic variables, you wont be having a problem when doing the read/write, but you might here have a race condition, and you could have random outputs depending on how windows decides to handle the threads.

Taking both things into account I would strongly recommend you to use some kind of synchronization in order to not get random results depending on how windows decides to handle your threads. Your gut in c++ is telling you something, because there is something going on here